# php serialize data with another column on database

Tags: php, mysql

i have allin table with serialize data and year like this

```
<pre>
+------+--------+------------------------------------------------+
|  id  |  year  |                  data                          |
+------+--------+------------------------------------------------+
|   1  |  2017  |   a:2:{s:3:"foo";s:1:"1";s:3:"bar";s:1:"2";}   |
+------+--------+------------------------------------------------+
|   2  |  2018  |   a:2:{s:3:"foo";s:1:"3";s:3:"bar";s:1:"4";}   |
+------+--------+------------------------------------------------+
from:
array("foo"=>"1","bar"=>"2"); //2017
array("foo"=>"3","bar"=>"4"); //2018
</pre>
```

this is my code

```
<?php

$year = date("Y");
$sql = "select * from allin"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $year =  $row["year"];
        $db =  $row["data"];
        $data = unserialize($db);
        //print_r($data);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo $data["foo"]; //how about selecting 2017 or 2018???
$conn>close();
?>
```

how can i select foo and bar in year 2018 and 2017?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change

```
 $data = unserialize($db);
```

to

```
 $data[$row["year"]] = unserialize($db);
```

Access it by

```
echo $data[2017]["foo"];
```